# How to open a location when clicking OK button on a vbs msgbox?

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbs msgbox like below. I want to open a location `C:\WORK` after user clicking the OK button. Is there an easy way to tell OK button what to do like using vbs in hta `onclick xxxx`

```
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )


x=msgbox("Dear user on " & strComputerName & vbcrlf & " " & vbcrlf & "There are more than 5 files saved on C:\WORK folder, Please clean up.", &h51000, "Clean up C:\work")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
wshShell.Run "explorer.exe /e,C:\Work"
```